# Apache Ignite REPLICATED cache entries not found

Tags: java, caching, ignite

My Ignite topology is 2 servers A and B with native persistence enabled, and two servers C and D with persistence disabled. There is a REPLICATED cache, it's declared on servers C and D in Java (also tried declarative way in XML) and propagated to A and B. Peer class loading is on.

Test case is trivial. The cache is populated on C with

```
cache.put(key, value)
```

Keys are `java.lang.String` objects, values are my POJOs, without any field annotations (SQL or affinity related).

Then, on server D the entry is queried with

```
cache.containsKey(key)
```

or

```
Iterator<Entry<String, MyPOJO>> it = cache.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
cache.query(new ScanQuery<String, MyPOJO>(null)).getAll().forEach(...);
```

All these methods do not return the value, which has been inserted on server C. Surprisingly,

```
cache.get(key)
```

does return the value. If I connect to the cluster with Ignite Visor (as a client node), it shows the entities stored on servers A and B.

It only happens if cache mode is REPLICATED. If changed to PARTITIONED, all the cache methods above work correctly and return the inserted values.

*UPDATE*

I don't have configuration XML at hand, so let me just describe it.

Nodes A and B:

- grid name is defined
- Kubernetes IP finder is defined, with Kubernetes service name and port configured
- native persistence is enabled

Nodes C and D:

- grid name is defined
- native persistence is not configured
- Kubernetes IP finder is defined
- cache configuration is defined, it consists of one entry, my own Java class which extends org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration and calls setName(), setCacheMode(), and a few other methods from constructor

I'll try to provide exact XML config shortly.

Comment: Which version of ignite do you use?

Comment: Ignite version is 2.6.0

Comment: Can you share exact nodes configurations? I don't understand why the cache will be declared on C&D but entries will be stored on A&B.